# Running Spring Boot application on JBoss Web Server

Tags: spring, jboss-web

Is it possible to run Spring boot application on JBoss Web Server rather than JBoss AP? If so, What are the pros and cons?

Comment: Did you mean JBoss EAP, instead of *JBoss AP*?

Comment: Yes, Jboss EAP.